# JMeter - Repeating query parameters from array variable

Tags: jmeter, integration-testing

Hi I'm kinda new to JMeter, and I'm looking to format my HTTP sampler in JMeter to take an array that I computed from a previous sampler with a JSON Extractor to test out another API.  For example, I have a variable computed in a previous step:

```
bookCollection=["acb123","bcd234","cde345"]
```

And I want to create a sampler to hit an API in this manner using the gathered data:

```
http://hostname/api/getBooks?id=acb123&id=bcd234&id=cde345
```

I tried using adding `id` to the parameter list with `${bookCollection}` but this somewhat predictably just put the array in string form, brackets included, in a single `id` parameter.  I don't see anything in the HTTP sampler that can expand an array into multiple repeating query parameters.  Any pointers to what JMeter settings or other JMeter test components (samplers/extractors) might work better is greatly appreciated.